# Android Studio 2.1.2 with Firebase NOT WORKING

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services

whenever I try initiating firebase, there's always these errors

```
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 11020000 but found 8489470
W/FA: Service connection failed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED, resolution=null, message=null}
E/FA: Discarding data. Failed to send app launch
E/FA: Failed to get app instance id
E/FA: Failed to send current screen to service
E/FA: Discarding data. Failed to send event to service
```

I get it's something related to Google Play Services but I just cant figure out how to fix it, I'm running Android Studio 2.1.2 and there's no update for Google Play Services in the SDKs

EDIT: My App Gradle (I'm using an emulator)

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.sc.voxcinemascamp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.2'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Show your app/build.gradle, I suspect gogole play services and firebase version mismatch

Comment: share your app gradle.

Comment: @user1209216 I added it

Comment: @Haidous use `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.0'` instead of `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.2'`

Comment: @arcticwhite didn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, it's clear now. You need either update your emulator to get Play Services 11 installed on it, or downgrade your firebase dependency to match Google Play Services installed on your emulator.

I would rather suggest to update emulator, don't downgrade Play Services used in your app because of emulator.

Comment: You can do that with Android Studio's sdk manager. Or try to deploy your app to physical phone, with Play Services 11 installed.

Comment: Even updating the error keeps on ```Failed to send current screen to service``` ```Discarding data. Failed to send event to service```

Comment: Is there a solution for this for when your app is out in the wild? (Forced upgrade of Google Play Services from within the app?)

Comment: @androidtitan you can force update Gogole Play Services, look here:  https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability and here: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability.html#getErrorDialog(android.app.Activity, int, int)

Answer (score 2):

**Uninstall your app on the emulator**---go to **home screen** of your **emulator**---open **google play** and **login with a gmail account**---as soon as youve logged in,you will get a google play update popup or notification that says application will not launch until google play services is updated..follow the screen prompts to update google play,then **run your application again**.

Answer (score 1):

Got same problem.The problem was in my emulator.Just upgraded my emulators google play services and it worked fine.Or try to run in another emulator which has upgrade version of google play services.